# What's the best way to handle logging in and out with multiples scopes/roles with Rails/Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, scopes

I've been searching through the Devise RDocs, Google, on this site for answers to my question, but no luck.

Let's say I have four Devise scopes/roles, and each one has their own attributes, login page, and separate web flows:

- Students
- Professors
- Deans
- Faculties

All of these use the User class and have the following attribues in common.

- Id
- Name
- Email
- Password
- Role

Here is an example of the routes I have established to set this up:

```
devise_for :students, :class_name => 'User'
devise_for :professors, :class_name => 'User'
devise_for :deans, :class_name => 'User'
devise_for :faculties, :class_name => 'User'
devise_for :users
```

Then I generated the devise scoped views and played around with those.

After that I had to add some code in my application controller to override Devise::RegistrationsController which wanted to route everything to the root path:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 user_role = resource.role
 case user_role
   when "professor"
     professors_url
   when "faculty"
     faculties_url
   when "dean" 
     deans_url
   when "student"
     students_url
   else
     root_path       
  end 
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  case resource
   when :faculty
     new_faculty_session_path
   when :professor
    new_professor_session_path
   when :dean 
     new_dean_session_path
   when :student
     new_student_session_path
   else
     root_path       
  end     
end
```

I have access to excellent helpers such as **signed_in?** which tells me if any user in any one of the scopes mentioned above is logged in.  Great!!!  Now I need similar functionality for **current_user**.

I have access to the following helpers.

- **current_student**
- **current_professor**
- **current_dean**
- **current_faculty**

They work perfectly, but here is where I have issues.  Let's say if I have a view that shares all of these scopes.  Now if I try **current_student** on that view and I'm logged in as a professor it won't work.

For example:  I have a partial that I want to include on every page to allow users to logout if they're logged in.  This is how I went about it for a student.  Works just fine.

```
<% if student_signed_in? %>
 <div style="float: right;">Welcome <%= current_student.name %></div>
 <div>
    <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_student_session_path, :method => :delete) %>        
 </div>
<% end %>
```

What I want to do is something like this which will provide the ability to logout all my scopes/resources regardless if I'm logged in as a student, dean, professor, or faculty:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
 <div style="float: right;">Welcome <%= current_resource.name %></div>
 <div>
    <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_resource_session_path, :method => :delete) %>        
 </div>
<% end %>
```

My next step would have been to add my own helper methods to determine the scope like so:

```
def current_resource
     current_professor unless current_professor.nil?
     current_student unless current_student.nil?
     current_dean unless current_dean.nil?
     current_faculty unless current_faculty.nil?
end

def destroy_resource_session_path
     destroy_professor_session_path unless current_professor.nil?
     destroy_student_session_path unless current_student.nil?
     destroy_dean_session_path unless current_dean.nil?
     destroy_faculty unless current_faculty.nil?
end
```

If this approach will work, I'd do it, but it seems highly inefficient and tedious if I decide to add more roles or common functionality in the future...

There has to be a better way?  This makes me feel like I'm using Devise incorrectly, or am just missing something somewhere.

Comment: I'm trying to emulate something similar to http://www.theworknumber.com/  Where Verifier, Employee, Employer have their own portals, just as Student, Dean, Professor, and Faculty have their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much more research I found a Gem called CanTango that does exactly what I was looking for.  It works with Devise and handles multiples User model types.  Take a look and see.

https://github.com/kristianmandrup/cantango/wiki/Cantango-with-devise-accounts

Thanks for answering my questions guys.  I learned a lot from your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) from Ryan bates? It allows you to use just the Devise user model, and define abilities based on role in your user model. It then gives you access to helper methods `can?` and `cannot?` to further define your abilities.

**EDIT:**
I would move the attributes to referenced models, and direct the web flow with CanCan. The examples that you see around the web don't always show the full capabilities that CanCan will give you. You could put links on your landing page to direct them to their appropriate login page which each have the same Devise sign in form. Keep you logic for the `after_sign_in_path_for`, and lock down restricted actions with CanCan. This simplifies your routes and the overall application logic and design. Plus it makes troubleshooting Devise errors 75% easier with only one model.

Comment: Yes I have the CanCan gem installed, but I haven't got as far as trying to use it.  I tried using the Devise User model alone, but I couldn't figure out a way to have separate login pages for all of my users because they have totally different web flows.  Students have separate attributes from a professor and different controllers.  Is there a way to do that with CanCan?

Comment: I edited my original post to reflect the differences between them, as the way I had it worded before made it seem as if the only difference was the role which CanCan would have been perfect for.  The Dean, Faculty, Student, and Professor models have their own attributes, login pages, and web flows, but they all belong to the User model.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look more into CanCan and see if I can pull it off.  I was thinking about using CanCan solely to prevent a Professor from navigating over to a Student's page and vice versa, but I could see how it could be used to drive the entire process.  I just have to figure out how lol.

Comment: The community is here to help bro. All of my companies apps use devise+canan much in the same way you are wanting. If you get stuck post and we'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments to the above answer, an alternative is to use multiple rails applications (one for each role), and either share the same DB across them (see this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690546/multiple-rails-app-single-mysql-database)), or make another application solely for authentication and authorization, and manage all sign ins through that.

The above solutions are really only a fallback if you don't want to use one app though. I'd recommend simply to keep doing what you're doing right now, determine the scopes and make methods that can deal with each case.

You can do this a little better with well designed methods. For example, modify `destroy_resource_session_path` to take in an argument, `current_user`, which is assigned to whichever of `current_professor, ... current_faculty` is not nil, and then call `destroy_#{current_user}_session_path`. To further elaborate on how to do this:

You don't need exactly need well-defined roles in your application, more of just routing each role to a different set of models/views/controllers , so the best way is to make a separate controller that determines the role, and routes requests to the appropriate controller based on the users role.

EDIT:

In general, I think you're going about it the right way, but you can make it better if you copy the methods that deal with different users (like the 2 you have) into a separate controller with actions like `destroy_resource_session_path`, and `current_resource`. Similarly, add the `after_sign_in_path_for` and `after_sign_out_path_for` methods to that new controller

The point is that the new controller should deal with differentiation between types of users, so adding a new type of user is as simple as adding a few lines to that controller only, and modifying `routes.rb`.

Just store a [set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-include-3F) of the roles you have in that controller. Then, you can modify your methods to use the set to figure out which roles exist, so all you have to do is add an entry to the set and an entry to `routes.rb` to add a new role. For example, you would modify `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` to:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  user_role = resource.role
  if (set_of_roles.include?(user_role))
    return #{user_role}_url
  else
    return root_path
  end
end
```

Note that `#{..}` is how you interpolate strings in ruby, so `#{user_role}_url` in ruby is equivalent to `user_role+"_url"` in Java.

With methods like that, the only thing you have to do to add a new role is to create a new view for that role, define a route called `role_name` in `routes.rb`, and add the role to `set_of_roles`.

I'd recommend researching the single sign-in idea before using it - I'm not familiar with it, but the answers on question I linked to on SO say it overcomplicates things.

Comment: In Java I would use a Factory to do something like this, but I'm still learning best practices in Ruby Rails.  Plus I have a feeling that this functionality is built into Devise, like signed_in?, and I'm just over looking it.  Any how in Ruby would I do something like this?  current_user is_a? Professor destroy_professor_session_path.

Comment: For this first go round I want to keep it as simple as possible.  A single-sign approach, as you suggested. would probably be implemented in the future though.

Comment: I didn't think #{user_role}_url would work because it is not a String URL, but a path being return from Rails helper methods based off my model <model_name>_url.  I was wondering if instead I could use url_for and pass the parameters dynamically like you are saying, but it didn't work the first time I tried it.  It complained about not being able to find a controller for my models, but clearly they are there.

Comment: @JasonH You're right, you should use `url_for`. As for the controller issue, if your model is named "X", then you should have a corresponding controller named "XsController". If you add further details in your question I'll take a look.

Comment: My controllers are named after my model objects.  When I use url_for {:controller => :deans, :action => :index}  I get cannot find Controller deans.  I haven't tried again, so I'll get back to you with my results this evening.

Comment: @JasonH Note that you have to generate the controller using `rails generate controller Deans <list of actions>`. Just making the file yourself won't be enough to make rails detect it.

Comment: I'm using the scaffolded controllers along with Devise.